# How can I avoid variables and individuals overlapping in a biplot?

Tags: r, pca

I can't figure out how to avoid the arrows hiding the individuals in my PCA
[image: ...]

I have used the repel function as follows:

```
fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE,
                col.var = "#2E9FDF",
                col.ind = "#696969")
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the RStudio tag. Please do not use it unless it is specifically for the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You could minimize the effect by using gradient color.

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
data(decathlon)

res.pca = PCA(decathlon[,1:12], scale.unit=TRUE, ncp=5, quanti.sup=c(11: 12), graph=T)

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE, col.ind = "cos2",
                gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
                col.var = "#2E9FDF")
```

[image]